# How to exclude empty value in PowerShell AD-Module?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I using a PowerShell command to extract "givenName", "sn", and "SamAccountName" from activeDirectory:

```
Get-ADUSer -Filter * -Properties givenName, sn, SamAccountName | Select givenName, sn, SamAccountName
```

The problem is sometimes in my result, i have empty values. 
For example:
givenName = Tom 
sn = 
SamAccountName = TomA1

How to exclude all empty value in my result to have only complete line ?

Answer (score 0):

I did that:

```
Get-ADUSer -Filter * -Properties givenName, sn, SamAccountName | Select givenName, sn, SamAccoun
tName | ? {$_.sn -ne $null} | ? {$_.givenName -ne $null}  | ? {$_.SamAccountName -ne $null} | Export-Csv C:\test.csv -Encoding UTF8
```